# java - spring security customize tomcat error pages

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I'm developing a java spring mvc project that uses Apache Tomcat 8.0.11 web server. I want to customize 400(bad request) and 404(not found) error pages. In the other words I want to show custom error pages instead of normal tomcat error pages. Is there any way for doing this in spring security? Note that I'm using **java based config** instead of xml based config. In fact, I want to customize this page:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add error page in your web.xml file like below

```
<display-name>App Name </display-name>
<error-page>
<error-code>123456</error-code>
<location>/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

And while sending response you can do as

```
response.sendError(123456,"Error Message");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried and it worked. Now, my question is how can I access error info like code and message inside the `error404.jsp` page? For example something like `${code}` .

Answer (score 1):

We can customize mentioned exception in multiple ways

1. based in error code we set the customized message to response object which we are through out to UI.
2. If we are using ReST service the API itself have exception API to customize exception. ex: WebApplicationException and ExceptionMapper etc..